# Which API does Java's jps tool use internally?

Tags: jmx, java, jdk-tools

I need to recreate the functionalities of the jps tool programmatically. I need to find out all Java running processes along with their id so I can attach to that process (similar to what JConsole does).

I thought the VirtualMachine API would help, but did not get expected result when I run the following

```
public class ProcessList {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<VirtualMachineDescriptor> vms = VirtualMachine.list();
        for(VirtualMachineDescriptor vm : vms){
            System.out.println (vm.id());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code above, it returns just one ID, but when I run jps on the same machine I see several other processes.

Answer (score 8):

`jps` uses an internal class - [`MonitoredHost`](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/serviceability/jvmstat/sun/jvmstat/monitor/MonitoredHost.html) of the Oracle/Sun JRE. The `activeVMs()` method is used to obtain the list of all active VMs on a host. You can refer to the source of the `sun.tools.jps.Jps` class of OpenJDK, to find out how the `jps` tool works under the hood.

Comment: This is correct.  I looked at the code for JPS class in sun.tools.jps.JPS and sun.tools.jstatd

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct API, ultimately 'MonitoredHost#activeVMs()' and 'VirtualMachine.list()' use the same discovery code via jstat technology. Do you run jps on the command line as a different user? In that case, you would see different JVMs.

See here how [JPS](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java.html) is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

you can do following :
1) Create platform specific script files (.bat for windows, .sh for linux etc)
2)Use "wmic process"(Windows), "ps -ef"(linux) etc commands in those scripts to list the processes (pipe on the result to get the java processes).
3)Launch the above scripts using Runtime's API and get the output result